# What will firebase.getInstance() get if there are multiple databases

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-analytics

I was using a firebase database in my Android app. Now I need to use another database but I want to know for the old versions of my app what will "firebaseDatabase.getInstance" return? Which database from my databases will be returned?

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
```

Comment: Retrieve an instance of your database using getInstance() and reference the location you want to write to. More information here : https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/

Answer (score 2):

`.getInstance()` function actually gets a string of *url* as an input parameter. You can see it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#getInstance(java.lang.String)).

Alternatively you can follow the tutorial [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/configure/#support_multiple_environments_in_your_android_application) to actually create more than one instance in one app with manually setting *FirebaseOptions*, *FirebaseApp* and *FirebaseDatabase* objects.

```
// Manually configure Firebase Options
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
        .setApplicationId("1:27992087142:android:ce3b6448250083d1") // Required for Analytics.
        .setApiKey("AIzaSyADUe90ULnQDuGShD9W23RDP0xmeDc6Mvw") // Required for Auth.
        .setDatabaseUrl("https://myproject.firebaseio.com") // Required for RTDB.
        .build();

// Initialize with secondary app.
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this /* Context */, options, "secondary");

// Retrieve secondary app.
FirebaseApp secondary = FirebaseApp.getInstance("secondary");
// Get the database for the other app.
FirebaseDatabase secondaryDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(secondary);
```

Please also read the notes in the end, as using different databases might confuse your *Google Analytics*, causing analytics data drops.